# Why is the javascript validation ending instead of doing the php validation

Tags: javascript, php, validation

Help! I cant seem to get my form to validate through javascript and then if successful to validate through php.What am I doing wrongly? After it checks through the javascript function it just reloads a blank checkout.php? I cant for the life of me figure out why this is happening. It needs to check javascript then if successful check php and then if that is successful as well to submit and go to a conformation.php page.

Javascript validation code:

```
function validateForm() {
    valid = true;
    var a=document.forms["checkout"]["fname"].value;
    if (a==null || a=="")
    {
    alert("First name must be filled out");
    valid = false;
    }
    var b=document.forms["checkout"]["lname"].value;
    if (b==null || b=="")
    {
    alert("Last name must be filled out");
    valid = false;
    }
    var c=document.forms["checkout"]["address"].value;
    if (c==null || c=="")
    {
    alert("Address must be filled out");
    valid = false;
    }   
    var d=document.forms["checkout"]["email"].value;
    if (d==null || d=="")
    {
    alert("Email address must be filled out");
    valid = false;
    }
    var e=document.forms["checkout"]["email"].value;
    if(!validateEmail(e)){
    alert("Must be a valid email address");
    valid = false;
    }   
    var f=document.forms["checkout"]["phone"].value;
    if (f==null || f=="")
    {
    alert("Phone number must be filled out");
    valid = false;
    }
    var g=document.forms["checkout"]["phone"].value;
    if(!validatePhone(g)){
    alert("Must be a valid phone number");
    valid = false;
    }   
    var h=document.forms["checkout"]["card"].value;
    if (h==null || h=="")
    {
    alert("Credit card info must be filled out");
    valid = false;
    }
    var i=document.forms["checkout"]["card"].value;
    if(!validateCard(i)){
    alert("Must be a valid credit card number");
    valid = false;
    }
    return valid;
}
 function validateEmail(email) {
    var pattern = new RegExp(/^[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,3})$/);
    return pattern.test(email);
}
function validatePhone(phone) {
    var ppattern = new RegExp(/^[\(]?(\d{0,3})[\)]?[\s]?[\-]?(\d{3})[\s]?[\-]?(\d{4})[\s]?[x]?(\d*)$/);
    return ppattern.test(phone);
}
function validateCard(card) {
    var cpattern = new RegExp(/(?:\d[ ]?){12,17}\d/);
    return cpattern.test(card);
}
```

php validation code:

```
if(isset($_POST['SubmitForm'])){
if(empty($_POST['fname'])){
    echo "First name cannot be empty!<br/><br/>";
    return false;
}
if(empty($_POST['lname'])){
    echo "Last name cannot be empty!<br/><br/>";
    return false;
}
if(empty($_POST['address'])){
    echo "Address field cannot be empty!<br/><br/>";
    return false;
}
if(empty($_POST['email'])){
    echo "Email field cannot be empty!<br/><br/>";
    return false;
}
if($_POST['email']){
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $regex = '/^[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,3})$/'; 
    $match = preg_match($regex,$email);
    if(!$match)
    echo "Not a valid email address!<br/><br/>";
    return false;
}
if(empty($_POST['phone'])){
    echo "Phone number cannot be empty!<br/><br/>";
    return false;
}
if($_POST['phone']){
    $phone = $_POST['phone'];
    $reg = '/^[\(]?(\d{0,3})[\)]?[\s]?[\-]?(\d{3})[\s]?[\-]?(\d{4})[\s]?[x]?(\d*)$/';
    $pmatch = preg_match($reg, $phone);
    if (!$pmatch)
    echo "Not a valid phone number!<br/><br/>";
    return false;
}
if(empty($_POST['card'])){
    echo "Card field cannot be empty!<br/><br/>";
    return false;
}
if($_POST['card']){
    $card = $_POST['card'];
    $match = preg_match("#[0-9]#",$card);
    if(strlen($card) < '13')
    echo "Card field must be at least 13 digits <br/><br/>";
    return false;
    if(!$match)
    echo "Card number must be numeric<br/><br/>";
    return false;
}
if($_POST['month']){
$month = $_POST['month'];
if($month < 05)
    echo "Expired credit card";
    return false;
}
return true;
$fname = $_SESSION['fname'];
    $lname = $_SESSION['lname'];
    $email = $_SESSION['email'];
    $phone = $_SESSION['phone'];
    $representation = json_encode($_SESSION['cart'],JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
    $pfile = fopen("orders.txt","a+");
    rewind($pfile);
    fwrite($pfile, "\r\n$fname:$lname:$email:$phone:$representation");
    fclose($pfile);
}
```

and lastly the form itself:

```
<form name = 'checkout' method='post' onsubmit="return validateForm()" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" accept-charset='UTF-8'>
<table style="border:thin solid #ccc;" rules="rows" cellpadding="6px" width="50%">
<tr><td>
</td></tr> 
<tr><td>First Name:<input type="text" name="fname" class="required" value="<?php if (isset($fname)){echo $fname;}?>" /></td></tr> 
<tr><td>
</td></tr> 
<tr><td>Last Name:<input type="text" name="lname" value="<?php if (isset($lname)){echo $lname;}?>" /></td></tr> 
<tr><td>
</td></tr> 
<tr><td>Address:</br><textarea name="address" id="address" value="<?php if (isset($address)){echo $address;}?>"></textarea></td></tr>
<tr><td>
</td></tr>  
<tr><td>Email:<input type="text" name="email" value="<?php if (isset($email)){echo $email;}?>"/></td></tr> 
<tr><td>
</td></tr> 
<tr><td>Phone:<input type="text" name="phone" value="<?php if (isset($phone)){echo $phone;}?>"/></td></tr> 
<tr><td>
</td></tr> 
<tr><td>Delivery method:<input type="radio" name="delivery"
    <?php if (isset($delivery) && $delivery=="regular post") echo "checked";?>
    value="regular post" checked>Regular Post
    <input type="radio" name="delivery"
    <?php if (isset($delivery) && $delivery=="courier") echo "checked";?>
    value="courier">Courier
    <input type="radio" name="delivery"
    <?php if (isset($delivery) && $delivery=="express courier") echo "checked";?>
    value="express courier">Express Courier</td></tr> 
<tr><td>
</td></tr> 
<tr><td>Credit Card No:<input type='text' name='card' maxlength='18' size='19' value="<?php if (isset($card)){echo $card;}?>"/></td></tr>
<tr><td>
</td></tr> 
<tr><td>Expiration Month:<select name="month">
    <option value="01">01</option>
    <option value="02">02</option>
    <option value="03">03</option>
    <option value="04">04</option>
    <option value="05">05</option>      
    <option value="06">06</option>
    <option value="07">07</option>
    <option value="08">08</option>
    <option value="09">09</option>
    <option value="10">10</option>
    <option value="11">11</option>
    <option value="12">12</option></select></td></tr>
<tr><td>
</td></tr> 
<tr><td>Expiration Year:<select name="year">
    <option value="2014">2014</option>
    <option value="2015">2015</option>
    <option value="2016">2016</option>
    <option value="2017">2017</option>
    <option value="2018">2018</option></select></td></tr>
<tr><td>
</td></tr> 
<tr><td><input type="checkbox" value="newsletter" name="letter[]">Check here to sign up for the newsletter</td></tr>    
<tr><td>
</td></tr> 
<tr><td colspan="2" align="left"><input type="submit" name="SubmitForm" value="Send"/></td></tr> 
</table>
```

Comment: Your Problem isn't clear. What do you mean? After successful validation in `javascript` Your `php` code doesn't validate or what?

Comment: Im not quite sure. If no problems occur within the javascript it instead reloads a blank checkout.php page instead of running a php check(i think) and then going to the conformation.php page once both are checked.

Comment: Just try `echo`ing `"Successful Validation"` before `return true`; in your `php` script. I Think the problem is entirely in that `return true` line. It should be at the end of  `fclose($pfile);` . Hope it helps.

Comment: You will have to show the whole script not just bits of it

Comment: @VedantTerkar I just tried echo "Successful Validation"; before the return true line in php and nothing appears. Im guessing the code errors somewhere but it isnt saying...

Comment: To be a bit more clear. I know the php code works fine on its own and the javascript works fine on its own but for some reason when trying to run both validation checks before submitting it loads a blank checkout.php page instead of a successful submission.

Comment: @RiggsFolly that is the whole code script.

Comment: Does it occur in the order you have shown i.e. php code and then html code? Edit the question and make a single code fragment for all the code in that file

Comment: @RiggsFolly the order its in is php then javascript then html

Comment: @VedantTerkar I just tried moving return true to the end of fclose and now its not even loading the html/form its just saying successful validation..lol

Comment: Ok I see something. Try some inteligent indentation of your php validation script and you should see the error quite quickly.

Comment: @RiggsFolly I don't see what your talking about >.>

Comment: Oh the missing brackets...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This part of your validation is wrong!

It will result in the validation always returning FALSE if you have a `$_POST['month']` passed to the validation.

It will also NEVER run the file generation as you have a `return true` before running the file creation code.

```
if($_POST['month']){
    $month = $_POST['month'];
    if($month < 05)
        echo "Expired credit card";

    return false;
}

return true;

$fname = $_SESSION['fname'];
    $lname = $_SESSION['lname'];
    $email = $_SESSION['email'];
    $phone = $_SESSION['phone'];
    $representation = json_encode($_SESSION['cart'],JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
    $pfile = fopen("orders.txt","a+");
    rewind($pfile);
    fwrite($pfile, "\r\n$fname:$lname:$email:$phone:$representation");
    fclose($pfile);
```

At a guess it should probably look something like this :

```
if($_POST['month']){
    $month = $_POST['month'];
    if($month < 05) {
        echo "Expired credit card";
        return false;
    }
}

$fname = $_SESSION['fname'];
$lname = $_SESSION['lname'];
$email = $_SESSION['email'];
$phone = $_SESSION['phone'];
$representation = json_encode($_SESSION['cart'],JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
$pfile = fopen("orders.txt","a+");
rewind($pfile);
fwrite($pfile, "\r\n$fname:$lname:$email:$phone:$representation");
fclose($pfile);

return true;
```